# Firefox Faulty %APPDATA%/mozilla folder

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

So i have a Problem with Firefoxes Profiles.

I'm logged in Windows with an user without admin rights. I install Firefox (providing an account with admin rights of course), and start it. If i start it as an Administrator, everything is fine. however starting it as a non-admin user, the Profile Manager opens *every time with no profiles*. It doesnt matter if i create a new Profile, next start everything is again empty. After Googleing a bit, i discovered, that the Profiles are stored in a `Profiles.ini` in `%APPDATA%/mozilla/...` i tried to open that file, but it seems that the whole `mozilla` folder under `%APPDATA%` is a link to the Administrators `%APPDATA%`. I cant be sure though, because i cant follow the link, even with administrative rights, and cant delete it.

It would be an acceptable solution to set the default Profiles Folder at Setup (with an command line parameter) if something like this is possible

Any Suggestions or Solutions?
Thanks

EDIT: The problem is recreatable. This is what i've done:

1. Log in as Administrator
2. install Firefox
3. log out *without having opened firefox*
4. log in as a normal user
5. start Firefox.

this time firefox didnt even asked for a Profile, it opened witout an adress bar and the "firefox" menu was really weird. Again i have `mozilla` folders in the `%APPDATA%` folders for every user, but its the same non-readable folder/link thing. even with administrative rights i cant delete any of them.

Comment: Firefox ships with an [external Profile manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager), which can be used to easily control multiple profiles, for multiple versions. Unfortunately, you cannot specify the location of `profiles.ini` (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution to your problem, but you can install and use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) without administrator privileges. From my experience, there is no difference in performance when installed on the same media as a normal Firefox installation.

Comment: this is not possible out of various reasons. it should be a normal installation